# Two different Symbols for the "same" project

Tags: eclipse, maven, cvs

I just saw that at a checkout with cvs, the projects have 2 different symbols. Strangely, most of the projects are the same. A few, however, are only to be found under a Project-symbol. Does anyone know what these symbols means?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not from the top of my head but you can probably figure this out by looking inside of the `.project` file. Usually, such overlays are added by project natures.

Compare the natures of the two projects, that should give you an idea.

Comment: Content of the .project -file

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
 <name>maven.root</name>
 <comment></comment>
 <projects>
 </projects>
 <buildSpec>
 </buildSpec>
 <natures>
 </natures>
</projectDescription>

Comment: In that case, the project has only the default "Generic Project" nature.